# Return variable from Test class to conftest

Tags: python, selenium, testing, pytest, fixtures

In my task, I need to return a value from my test class to conftest file.
is it possible? if yes then how to do it?

Suppose that I need to return 'element_2' variable from test case file.
If possible, please help.

This is my conftest file..

```
import pytest
import time
from selenium import webdriver


@pytest.yield_fixture(scope="function")
def oneTimeSetUp(request):

    print "__CONFTEST ONE TIME SETUP BEGIN__"
    driver=webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.maximize_window()    
    yield driver

    print "__CONFTEST YIELD BEGIN__"

    #print "ELEMENT_2 TEXT IS------>",element_2.text
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.close()
```

This is my test case file:

```
import pytest


@pytest.mark.usefixtures("oneTimeSetUp")

class TestHomePage():

    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def setup(self,oneTimeSetUp):
        self.webdriver = oneTimeSetUp            

    def test_run(self):

        print "____ TEST START ____"

    self.webdriver.get("https://www.google.co.in/")
    element_1 = self.webdriver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[name="btnI"]')
    print "CLICK ON 'I AM FEELING LUCKY'"   
    element_1.click()
    element_2 = self.webdriver.find_element_by_css_selector('a[href="/doodles/about"]') 
    print "ELEMENT_2 TEXT IS------>",element_2.text
    print "CLICK ON 'ABOUT' "
    #element_2.click()
    #return element_2   

        print "____ TEST END ____"
```

The above code is example of Google homepage then click on "I am feeling lucky" on that option I need to return the variable 'element_2' which is the element of "about" option which is present on the top left corner of that page.

Comment: Do you have an error message during running your script?

Comment: the above code is running i need to do a commented portions of the code

Comment: i need to return a variable "element_2" to my conftest file. and want to print "element_2.text" in conftest file.
is it possible?

Comment: How is going? Was my answer helpful? If yes -- check a tick near my answer, please.